# Cummulative Recursion

Tags: java, recursion

I want to recursively call payDay(day) which will return the cumulative amount made from day 1 to the day inputed if 1 penny doubles every day starting from day 1.  I have gotten the method to return the amount the inputed day is worth but I can't figure out how to add up all the prior days to this:

```
public static double payDay(int day) {
    if (day == 1) {
        return 0.01;
    } else {
         return 2 * payDay(--day);
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems solvable in a simple multiplication.

Comment: I assume the problem must be solved using recursion, @AdmiralAdama.

Comment: why not just `return 0.01 * 2(day - 1)` ?

Answer (score 2):

Your way you are using recursion to find the amount of pennies on day `n`.  To recursively find the total (the sum of all days) you can use a formula to calculate what is paid on day `n` and add day `n-1` as the recursive part:

Use the formula: `2^(n-1)` for day `n` and recurse on this:

```
package test;

public class Main {
    public static double payDay(int day) {
        if (day == 1) {
            return 1;
        }

        return Math.pow(2, day - 1) + payDay(day - 1);
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println("Day " + i + " " + payDay(i) + " pennies");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would bracket the 2^n - 1 (e.g. 2^(n-1)) for clarity. But +1 for a good answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use recursion at all. From what I gather you are trying to sum a finite geometric series.

```
double payDay(int day) {
    return 0.01 * (Math.pow(2.0, day) - 1.0);
}
```

day = 1 returns 0.01

day = 2 returns 0.01 + 0.02

day = 3 returns 0.01 + 0.02 + 0.04

Comment: This is probably homework, so recursion is the point, I'd guess

Comment: You're probably correct but it's a alternative worth noting I guess.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static double payday(double day) { 
  if (day == 1) {
     return 0.01;
  } else if (day > 1 && day <= 31) {
     return 2*payday(- - day);
  }
  return  day;
}
```